# How to set default page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've just published my site in my server, but when I type in the browser www.mysite.com  I get this error : HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
    The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.However if I type www.mysite.com/Home.aspx it loads correctly. So, how can I set the default page?? I already have this in my web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument>
     <files>
       <add value="Pages/Home.aspx" />
     </files>
   </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

### ASP.NET WebForms

On the `web.config` file, try this to use the `clear` tag before:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="Pages/Home.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Take a look here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

### ASP.NET MVC / ASP.NET CORE

Depending of the version of asp.net mvc you are using, you can have it on a different file (`~/Global.asax.cs` in v3 or older or `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` in v4 or newer). In both cases, you will see something register the routes, because asp.net mvc uses routes instead files like webforms. So, you can change the default values:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new 
        { 
            controller = "Home", // default controller
            action = "Index",  // default action on the controller
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

It is similar on the **ASP.NET CORE**.

Take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624181/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Okey so if the default page which I want to load is placed at folder (in this case "Pages") Do I have to add "Pages/Home.aspx" in default document???

Comment: Would this work for a document not in the root directory? for example if I want my default index to be "mydomain.com/folder1/index.html"

Comment: @Felipe, It did not work with me, I am using IIS Express in ASP.net Web Form

Comment: You wrote "It is similar on the ASP.NET Core" but there is no "id = UrlParameter.Optional", so it is an error.

Comment: If you use an ampersand, make sure you use &amp; instead of &

Answer (score 7):

Besides Felipe's answer, you can also do this from IIS.

Select `Admin Tools` --> `IIS Manager` --> Select your website from the list. Click on `Default Document` on the right hand side and Click `Add`. Move the entry to the top of the list using the arrows. You are done.

This will be overwritten each time you publish your site, however.

Comment: Adding for any other weary travelers -- this is overridden next time you publish your site.