# Error page loads(randomly) even the startup screen is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, error-handling, html

[image: Error]

Error page loads for the first time randomly. When press the refresh button it automatically loads the selected startup screen in ASP.NET C# Web application. Refer image

Comment: Please provide your code for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Added the default page to the web.config file

```
  <defaultDocument>
  <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="/Pages/Login/UserNamePwdLogin.aspx" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="index.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
            <add value="iisstart.htm" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set Default page then you need to redirect to default page if credentials fail or access to any other page directly to url.

You may get many examples of how to set default page, one of them is following

[How to set default page asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002744/how-to-set-default-page-asp-net)