# How to redirect the main URL to new path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, redirect, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.NET MVC, In localhost, using the web, I changed the start URL option it works fine there, once I published it to the main domain, it is not working on that. I hope anyone can help me. I want to redirect from 
domain.com/
to 
domain.com/Home/Index
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18002766/8160563

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your default route as this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

on startup the default route is initialized and hence redirected to the above website as

domain.com/Home/Index