# How to deploy my existing webapp on azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I've followed YouTube tutorials and MS docs to deploy my existing webapp to azure App Services, but it returns to me the page with default content of a new project.

[image]

Below is my file structure, "testHtml" is my start page, maybe there is something wrong with the structure, if so, how do I make change.

[image]

Comment: Since you are using MVC, you should define your startup page in [`RegisterRoutes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18002766/7073340)

Comment: @Jayendran  I tried replacing "Default" with my page "testHtml" in RouteConfig.cs, also tried adding <system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="Pages/Home.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that you need to set the [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents) for the Azure App service.

If it is deployed correctly, then it should work.

[image]